# Get details of product recently added to cart in WooCommerce and trigger a Google Analytics Add to Cart event

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

**Goal-** I am trying to run a Google Analytics Script using functions.php when a product is successfully added to the cart.

**The problem -**
Unable to get the details of the product added to the cart.

**What I tried-**
I tried to add the following code in functions.php to understand if I am getting the details properly. But the script doesn't seem to be working.

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart', 10, 6);
function custom_add_to_cart($cart_item_key,$product_id,$quantity,$variation_id,$variation,$cart_item_data
) {
?>
    <script>
        console.log("<?php echo 'Product ID ' . $product_id; ?>");
        console.log("<?php echo 'Quantity ' . $quantity; ?>");
        console.log("<?php echo 'Variation ID ' . $variation_id; ?>");
        console.log("<?php echo 'Product ' . $variation; ?>");
        console.log("<?php echo 'Cart Data ' . $cart_item_data; ?>");
    </script>
<?php
}
```

**If the problem is resolved-** Once I get details successfully in console, I would pass the values in the following Google Analytics Script

```
gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",//Will be replaced by product id
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Read this - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/google-analytics-integration/

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, will check. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

***How I figured out the solution & how it worked for me***

**1.** I figured out that whenever a product is added to the cart, the site is automatically redirected to the cart page.

**2.** Then I realized that the last added item gets added last in the item array, which made me use the cart page to trigger the add to cart instead of the cart page itself.

**3.** I used a Woocommerce hook available on the cart page, and then find the last item in the cart array.

**4.** Then I kind of ended and started the PHP script so that the Google Analytics event can be placed on the HTML.

**5.** Now I realized that some people can click on the cart and the cart page will still trigger the add to the cart item event. So I added a simple IF statement to run the google analytics event code only if the referrer is other than the cart page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents', 'google_analytics_custom_add_to_cart');
function google_analytics_custom_add_to_cart() {
    $prod_ids = array(); 
    global $woocommerce;
    $prods = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $custom_last_item_index= count($prods)-1;
    // loop products
    foreach($prods as $p => $values) { 
        $product_detail =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());
        array_push($prod_ids, $product_detail->get_id());
    }
    ?>
        <script>
            // understand the referrer
            if(document.referrer!="https://websitename/cart/"){
                gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
                  "items": [
                    {
                      "id": "<?php echo $prod_ids[$custom_last_item_index] ;?>",
                    }
                  ]
                });
            }
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

It may not be the most straightforward or the best answer, but it did help me. Hence thought of sharing it with you all.

Comment: I like this approach. Two caveats: 1) you have to pass in a 'item_id' or 'item_name' as well as 'currency' and 'value' - for GA4 they are mandatory. 2) gtag might not be available yet (it loads in the footer in my case due to bootstrapping from GTM and Firebase...)  so I wrapped the JS stuff in jQuery(document).ready(function () { } therefore it waits for gtag to be available. It works as a charme. Thank you.